# How to make the product single photos vertical? (woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to stack all the images on the product page one above the other, without thumbnails, instead of having only one large image above the thumbnails. Many fashion stores showcase this effect on their product pages, as seen in this example https://cubitts.com/products/judd . Here is the link to the page I need assistance with: https://k4rma.com.br/?product=hoodie-metal